# simple MVC example not working on MAMP localhost

Tags: php, localhost, url-routing, mamp

Following this tutorial: http://johnsquibb.com/tutorials/mvc-framework-in-1-hour-part-one

I've got the following code:

index.php

```
<?php

// Define document paths
define('SERVER_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/Library');
define('SITE_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs')

// Fetch the router
require_once(SERVER_ROOT . '/controllers/' . 'router.php');
```

router.php

```
<?php

//fetch the passed request
$request = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//parse the page request and other GET variables
$parsed = explode( '&' , $request);

//the page is the first element
$page = array_shift($parsed);

//the rest of teh array are get stateemnts, parse them out.
$getVars = array();
foreach ($parsed as $argument)
{
//split GET vars along '=' symbol to separate variable, values
list($variable, $value) = split('=' , $argument);
$getVars[$variable] = $value;
}

//this is a test, and we will be removing it later

print "the page you requested is '$page'";
print '<br/>';
$vars = print_r($getVars, TRUE);
print "The following GET Vards we passed to the page:<pre>".$vars."</pre>";
```

punch in this url:

```
http://localhost/MVC_test/index.php?news&article=howtobuildaframework
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

My MAMP home pages says my doc root is: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` and my server root is: `/Applications/MAMP/Library`

Last, the path to the index file is: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MVC_test/index.php`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have syntax error in your index.php, you forgot to put a semicolon on fourth line, so change code from

```
// Define document paths
define('SERVER_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/Library');
define('SITE_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs')
```

to this

```
// Define document paths
define('SERVER_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/Library');
define('SITE_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs');
```

Secondly loooks like you are not defining the above two variables with correct path make sure the SERVER_ROOT and SITE_ROOT are correct, for me SITE_ROOT should be something like

```
 define('SITE_ROOT', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MVC_test');
```

Comment: Thanks for response!  I fixed by stupid syntax error and tried the `SITE_ROOT` you suggested with no luck.  Can you show me some generic way to sort out these paths?